# I want to perform object detection using Yolov8(TFLite)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, yolo, yolov8

I want to convert YoloV8 to TensorFlowLite type for object detection.
I was able to get as far as the conversion, but I am stuck on the object detection part.
Can someone please advise me on this?
The execution environment is GoogleColaboratory.

**Conversion to TensorFlowLite**
ultralytics installation

```
!pip install ultralytics
```

Conversion of yoloV8 to TensorFlowLite

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
model = YOLO('yolov8m.pt')
results = model.export(format='tflite')
```

**Object detection**

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import tensorflow as tf

model_path = '/content/yolov8m_saved_model/yolov8m_float32.tflite'
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=model_path)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

image_path = f'/content/test.jpg'

image = Image.open(image_path)
image = image.resize((640, 640))
image = np.array(image, dtype=np.float32) / 255.0
image = image[np.newaxis, ...]

interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], image)
interpreter.invoke()

output = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])

boxes = output[..., :4]  # bounding box coordinates
confidence = output[..., 4:5]  # coefficient of confidence
class_probs = output[..., 5:]  # class probability

detections = []
for i in range(len(output)):
    for j in range(output.shape[1]):
        # Obtaining bounding box coordinates
        x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max = boxes[i][j]
        # Obtaining class probabilities
        class_probabilities = class_probs[i][j]
        # Select Class ID
        class_id = np.argmax(class_probabilities)
        # Add class probability, class ID, and bounding box coordinate information to the list
        detections.append([confidence[i][j], class_id, x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max])
```

This is the kind of code we use.
I don't have any errors, but I can't get the results I want.
I have the contents of the output, but how do I get the coordinates of the bounding box or the confidence level from here?
Please provide specific methods or references.

Comment: As I understand yolov8 doesn't automatically implement NMS during the TFLite conversion. You have to follow manual post-processing after the model inference to perform the NMS and then get the expected inference results. For more information see this discussion about TFLite inference output data: https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/issues/4266, and about implementing NMS to TFLite model: https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/issues/4427